# How to return NSData from NSURLSessionDataTask completion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsurlsession

I am trying to make a simple class that I can use to call a post web service.

Everything is working perfectly except that I am not able to return the `NSData`.

This is my code:

```
+ (NSData *)postCall:(NSDictionary *)parameters fromURL:(NSString *)url{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
    NSMutableArray *pairs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(NSString *key in parameters){
        [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, parameters[key]]];
    }
    NSString *requestParameters = [pairs componentsJoinedByString:@"$"];
    NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[requestParameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        //return data;
    }];
    [dataTask resume];

    return nil;
}
```

Please notice that I have `//return data` but it gives me this error

```
 Incompatible block pointer types sending 'NSData *(^)(NSData *__strong, NSURLResponse *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSData *__strong, NSURLResponse *__strong, NSError *__strong)'
```

My question is:

1. Is my way good or it will cause me problems in the future? I don't have image to download and I don't have anything to upload, I just have to send simple string data and receive simpe string data. Or it will be better to but that code in each function independently?
2. How can I return the data please?

Comment: BTW, you are concatenating your request parameters with `$`. Is that a correct? Generally you use `&`. You also generally percent escape the `parameters[key]` value with `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` (not `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23635327/1271826.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot just return the data (because the `NSURLSessionDataTask` runs asynchronously). You probably want to employ your own completion block pattern, similar to the `completionHandler` of the `dataTaskWithRequest` method.

So, you would add your own block parameter to your method, that you'll invoke from inside the `dataTaskWithRequest` method's `completionHandler`:

```
+ (NSURLSessionDataTask *)postCall:(NSDictionary *)parameters fromURL:(NSString *)url completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler {

    // create your request here ...

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (completionHandler)
            completionHandler(data, response, error);
    }];

    [dataTask resume];

    return dataTask;
}
```

Or, because this `dataTaskWithRequest` runs on a background thread, it’s sometimes useful to make sure to dispatch the completion handler back to the main queue, e.g.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (completionHandler)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionHandler(data, response, error);
        });
}];
```

Note, as an aside, I think it's good to return the `NSURLSessionDataTask` reference, like above, so (a) the caller can make sure the data task was successfully created; and (b) you have the `NSURLSessionTask` reference that you can use to cancel the task in case, at some future date, you want to be able to cancel the request for some reason (e.g. the user dismisses the view controller from which the request was issued).

Anyway, you'd then invoke this with:

```
NSURLSessionTask *task = [MyClass postCall:parameters fromURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // put whatever code you want to perform when the asynchronous data task completes
}];

if (!task) {
    // handle failure to create task any way you want
}
```

---

You ask:

> Is my way good or it will cause me problems in the future? I don't have [an] image to download and I don't have anything to upload, I just have to send [some] simple string data and receive [simple] string data. Or it will be better to but that code in each function independently?

If you're receiving simple string data back, I'd suggest composing your response in JSON format, and then having the completion block in `postCall` use `NSJSONSerialization` to extract the response. Using JSON makes it easier for the app to differentiate between successful response and a variety of server related problems that might also return string responses.

So, let's say you modified your server code to return a response like so:

```
{"response":"some text"}
```

Then you could modify `postCall` to parse that response like so:

```
+ (NSURLSessionDataTask *)postCall:(NSDictionary *)parameters fromURL:(NSString *)url completionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *responseString, NSError *error))completionHandler {

    // create your request here ...

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (completionHandler) {
            if (error) {
                completionHandler(nil, error);
            } else {
                NSError *parseError = nil;
                NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

                completionHandler(responseDictionary[@"response"], parseError);
            }
        }
    }];

    [dataTask resume];

    return dataTask;
}
```

In terms of your underlying question, whether a method like `postCall` makes sense, yes, I think it makes perfect sense to put the details of creating the request in a single method. My minor reservation in your implementation was your decision to make it a class method rather than an instance method. You're currently creating a new `NSURLSession` for each request. I'd suggest making `postCall` an instance method (of a singleton if you want) and then saving the session as a class property, which you set once and then re-use on subsequent queries.

Comment: Many thanks for the efforts but, unfortunately, I am not able to check the answer tonight since I am a little busy. However, I will check it tomorrow. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Rob and I fixed the errors in the original as well.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I was fixing a lot of errors in posts yesterday with terrible grammar, nonstandard code formatting and I must have simply seen errors and fixed them.  In other posts, I want back and fixed the original poster's misspellings and must have missed the ones in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a block method.

First define a block

```
typedef void (^OnComplete) (NSData *data);
```

Use the following method

```
+ (void)postCall:(NSDictionary *)parameters fromURL:(NSString *)url withBlock:(OnComplete)block; {

     NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
        NSMutableArray *pairs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(NSString *key in parameters){
            [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, parameters[key]]];
        }
        NSString *requestParameters = [pairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
        NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[requestParameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            block(data);
        }];
        [dataTask resume];
   }
```

Comment: I appreciate the efforts very much. Sorry but I won't be able to check it tonight because I am busy. However, I will check it tomorrow. +1 anyway.